# r ggplot - placing annotations in concentric circles chart using coord_polar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I made a chart of concentric circles using `ggplot` + `geom_bar` + `polar_coord`, and I am struggling with placing the annotations in the correct spot. Take the following code, modified from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52123169/manipulate-delineation-of-geom-bar-and-coord-polar-in-ggplot2-r) I asked and its satisfactory answer.

```
df <- data.frame(A=letters[1:12],
                 B=c(rep("Dim_1",4),rep("Dim_2",4),rep("Dim_3",4)),
                 C=c(rep("Ind_1",2),rep("Ind_2",2),rep("Ind_3",2),rep("Ind_2",2),rep("Ind_5",2),rep("Ind_6",2)))

ggplot(df, aes(factor(1), fill = C)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, colour = NA) +                       
  stat_count(aes(yintercept = cumsum(rev(..count..))),     
             geom = "hline") +                             
  coord_polar()+
  annotate("text",label = "A", x = 1, y = 2.5,size=2)+
  annotate("text",label = "B", x = 1, y = 3.5,size=2)
```

Here is what I get:

[image: This is what I get]

The problem is placement. I would like to place the `annotate` text around the circle. But since I created the chart from a `geom_bar` of 1 observation, I can move the texts only along the vertical axis.

How do I freely place my annotations in the chart? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't clearly get the question but...annotate freely with geom_text instead as follows:

```
    ggplot(df, aes(factor(1), fill = C)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, colour = NA) +                       
  stat_count(aes(yintercept = cumsum(rev(..count..))),     
             geom = "hline") +                             
  coord_polar()+
  geom_text(label="A",x=1.2,y=2.5)+
  geom_text(label="B",x=1.5,y=3.5)
```

This gives:
[image]

You can edit as you wish.

Comment: You're right. More straighforward than I thought. Since the x & y placements make intuitive sense for the bar chart but not the concentric circles chart, you may want to consider explaining how these placements map after the coord_polar conversion.

Comment: Hi, I've looked at the documentation of both functions. Not really sure to be honest. I thought it had to do with the lack of an `aes` mapping to `annotate` but not really sure. Hopefully an expert can help explain why.